# Alternative approach to fufilling a responsive web design when it come to absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to position 4 lines of text that is wrapped in a div onto an image at a certain position.

[image: enter link description here]

Here is the html and css code related to that picture:

```
    <div class="hero-img">
      <img src="img/welcome-hero.png" alt="Editor with Welcome Message">
      <div class="welcoming-animation">
        <span class="line-1 welcome-text">H</span>
        <span class="line-2 welcome-text">E</span>
        <span class="line-3 welcome-text">L</span>
        <span class="line-4 welcome-text">O</span>
      </div>

    </div>

 // CSS
    .hero-img{
      position:relative;
    }
    .hero-img img{
      display: block;
      margin:auto;
      margin-bottom:-5px;
    }
    .welcoming-animation{
      position:absolute;
      top:35px;
      left:68px;
    }
    .welcome-text{
      display: block;
    }
```

Shown in the picture, I want to put that line of text in the corner of the terminal image and make it responsive. I came to realize that if I use absolute positioning, then it will be a pain in the butt to make it responsive(having to keep track of different position for every small adjustment to the window).

I wanted to ask you CSS experts if there was another way of positioning that div of text so that I can easily make it responsive.

Comment: PS: I have tried using % measurements as well

Comment: Can you specify how you want to make it responsive, like how it looks like on desktop and on tablet and mobile? Since the word 'HELO' is align vertically I don't see you need to re-position it even in responsive view

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way would be to use the scale() css function to scale down your element past a certain breakpoint.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale

This method may cause anti-aliasing issues to your text (slight blurring) which may make it look less than ideal.

---

Alternatively, you could substitute your welcome animation div with an svg and animate it instead. The svg will retain its dimensions and position when resized so you do not have to deal with absolute positioning on the characters.

https://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/